# Can I get the form-data including text and file within one map in spring controller?

Tags: java, spring

I have a postman request like this.
[Example Postman Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpR8M.png)

I tried to get it like this.

My RestController:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Upload", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
public String upload(@RequestParam Map<String, Object> input, @RequestParam Map<String, MultipartFile> files){
    
    log.info("testing Upload: " + input);
    log.info("testing Upload: " + files);
    
    return "Ended";
}
```

My Result Log:

```
testing Upload: {id=123}
testing Upload: {2=org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile@b3fbcd9, 1=org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile@7c7d3381}
```

Can I get all the form-data within one map<String, Object>?

Expected map:

```
{2=org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile@b3fbcd9, id=123, 1=org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile@7c7d3381}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below line prints the map i.e, your key as String and value as MultipartFile object

```
log.info("testing Upload: " + files);
```

if you're only interested in file name, you can iterate over the keys and get the name of the file from the value.

```
for(Map.Entry<String, MultipartFile> entry: files.entrySet()) {
    log.info(entry.getKey() + "=" +entry.getValue().getOriginalFilename());
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my bad presentation. My question is not how to print the map correctly. I am asking how to get the form-data within one map including ordering

Comment: I have already updated my expected map. Sorry very much

Comment: ok, you can create a third map<String, Object> and iterate over both the maps one by one and populate this third map. The potential issue with your requirement 1). if duplicate keys are present in either of map, this third map will overwrite it. 2). data retrieval issue, you would always need to check type of value before using it i.e., type casting it to MultipartFile object.

Comment: It is not fit my requirement. In my controller is already split into two maps so I am already lost the ordering. Do I have any way to get the form-data in one map/multivaluemap? for the point 2, yes I want to iterate the one map and check the object class for my next process